# CSS dropdown menu not working with position:relative?

Tags: html, css

I want to build a simple CSS dropdown menu. It works if I use absolute positioning, but starts to push down the content if I use relative positioning. What is the reason for this? Using absolute positioning for the DIVs menu and content is not an option for me unfortunately.

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="topmenu">
        <a href="">Top 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="submenu"><a href="">Sub 1</a></li>
          <li class="submenu"><a href="">Sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
Test
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
  position:relative;  
}

#menu ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  list-style-image:none;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

#menu li.topmenu {
  float:left;
}

.topmenu a {
  float:left;
  width:110px;
}

.topmenu ul{
  display:none;
}

.submenu a{
  width:110px;
  clear:both;
}

.topmenu:hover ul {
  display:block;  
  z-index:10;
}
#content {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: You should read up on the difference between absolute and relative positioning, and how they work in the Dom.

Comment: Why is `position:absolute` not an option? It is the standard method of creating dropdown menus.

Comment: When using absolute positioning in the example above I would need to give the content div a top property, right? However I don't know the actual height of the menu.

Comment: You don't need to know the height, just use `top:100%` on the **submenu**...and it will always adjust automatically. You shouldn't be positioning the content div at all. The `li` of the parent list would receive `position:relative`.

Comment: Shouldn't the submenu always be displayed at the very end of the page with "top:100%"?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z8g3w9so/ That is why the `li` should have `position;relative`, the submenu is then positioned absolutely **with reference to the parent list item**. You really should read up some more. - https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/110-quick-overview-of-css-position-values/

Comment: Again, Axel, you really should read up on how the work.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me Pauli_D. I really misunderstood the concept of absolute, as being "absolutely" absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified the code, removed the horrible floats and substituted with `display: inline-block` and fixed the positioning issue.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/50kdpz0r/))

```
#menu ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
#menu li {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
#menu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    width:110px;
}
```